# Get File by name in docs.google

Tags: google-apps-script

What am I doing wrong?
I want to get a link to google drive from the file name in the cell

```js
function main (file){
  return DriveApp.getFilesByName(file).next().getUrl();
}
```

But I get a "name" error.
I don't even have such a variable

Exception: Invalid argument: name

main    @ test.gs:2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to run the function `main()` directly via the 'Run' button in Script Editor. This way the function gets no arguments. You have to call the `main()` function from another function.

Something like this:

```
// this is the function to run via Run button
function myFunction() {
  var url = main('test file');
  console.log(url);
}

function main(file) {
  return DriveApp.getFilesByName(file).next().getUrl();
}
```

[image]

Comment: a little bit wrong

I'm just trying to pass a parameter to a function.
I have a column in the table with the names of the files.
I want to get in the next column links to files

Comment: but even in this case it does not work
Exception: Invalid argument: name

main @ Макросы.gs:8

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with the variable `file`. Can you show how the log (`console.log(file);`) looks like? It should be a string (a file name).

Comment: если я создаю переменную с именем файла, то все ОК

function main(file) {
  var text = "2204_ALL_13.pdf";
  console.log(text);
  console.log(file);
  return DriveApp.getFilesByName(text).next().getUrl();
}

17:57:44 info 2204_ALL_13.pdf
17:57:44 info undefined

Comment: если я пытаюсь получить имя файла как параметр, то ошибка

function main(file) {
  var text = "2204_ALL_13.pdf";
  console.log(text);
  console.log(file);
  return DriveApp.getFilesByName(file).next().getUrl();
}

18:01:19 info 2204_ALL_13.pdf
18:01:19 info undefined
18:01:19 error Exception: Invalid argument: name

main @ Макросы.gs:11

Comment: console.log(file);

receives  undefined

Comment: he doesn't see the file name, then how is it correct?

Comment: Well. Now it's time to examine more closely how exactly you're getting the variable `file` before you pass it into the function. Could you please to show this part of the code? `var file = ...`

Comment: briefly:
I want to add a custom function to the table.
column A contains the names of the files.
Column B contains the formula `=ToLink(A1)`

column A itself is formed from `=concat(Concat($D$1;TEXT(C 17;"0"));". pdf")`

Column C contains a variable for files (files have already been uploaded)

Comment: so a file is an argument to a function
`function main(file)`

Comment: So do you mean **SpreadsheetApp** after all? Since in your question 'docs' is mentioned (which looks like **DocumentApp**)? A custom function (in SpreadsheetApp) can't perform the command `Drive.getFilesByName()`. You can't do it via a custom function. It can be done via custom menu, button, a side panel, etc.

Comment: Hmm,
so I need to assign a button and use it to transfer those cells for this function?

Comment: The possible implementation depends on your workflow. I'd prefer to add a custom menu. But it can be a button as well. I think the script could grab all the file names from column A and add their URLs into column B. Nothing fancy. Except the script should be called manually (with a button or a menu item).